# Kentico 11 Scheduled Tasks will not run in Custom Classes

Tags: scheduled-tasks, kentico, windows-task-scheduler

I have built 2 custom scheduled tasks under my 'Site1' on an instance of Kentico 11. There are several scheduled tasks running under 'Site1'. Most run code from Kentico's CMS libraries such as CMS.Membership.DeleteNonActivatedUser.

My 2 Custom Scheduled tasks reside in the App_Code folder.

```
using CMS;
using CMS.EventLog;
using CMS.Scheduler;
using System;

[assembly: CMS.AssemblyDiscoverable]
[assembly: RegisterCustomClass("CustomTask1", typeof(namespaceName.CustomTask1))]
[assembly: RegisterCustomClass("CustomTask2", typeof(namespaceName.CustomTask2))]
namespace namespaceName
{
    public class CustomTask1 : ITask
    {
        public string Execute(TaskInfo task)
        {
            try
            {
                EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.INFORMATION, "CustomTask1", "Task Begin", "Task is working.");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.ERROR, "CustomTask1", "Task Error", "Task threw exception: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public class CustomTask2 : ITask
    {
        public string Execute(TaskInfo task)
        {
            try
            {

                EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.INFORMATION, "CustomTask2", "Task Begin", "Task is working.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.ERROR, "CustomTask2", "Task Error", "Task threw exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My CustomTask1 and CustomTask2 appear in the Class dropdown list in the Kentico Task Scheduler. I've set both Tasks up to run every day at 6:00 AM. and the Enabled checkbox is checked. none of the checkboxes below are checked. When I click the green triangle on the task list page I get the popup message that says it's running. But nothing is logged in the event logs and neither the last run datetime nor the run counter change.

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this? I have multiple custom scheduled tasks running in a different instance of Kentico and they are working fine, but I cannot get this instance to run my custom tasks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using web site or web application project type? In other words - was the App_Code folder present or you had to create it manually?

Comment: Kentico 11 is running in a web site. The App_Code folder was already present and has a lot of custom code that runs fine.

Comment: Have you tried removing the class file and adding it back again and re-registering the scheduled tasks? I just copied your code into my Kentico 11 instance, registered the tasks and it is working fine, some screen shots: https://www.screencast.com/t/LKL3kwohN ; https://www.screencast.com/t/80nu0iaSrK and https://www.screencast.com/t/B5ejjRdy4gq so maybe there is some evil Lepricon causing this on your side...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need this in version 11:

`[assembly: CMS.AssemblyDiscoverable]`

If you look into the Event Log after your site restarts, can you see the AppStart event that is loading the modules when the system restarts?  If not your app may not be registering that custom code.  At that point, it may be worth building that code locally and seeing if there are any errors.

Comment: The AppStart event lists a whole laundry list of CMS libraries it has loaded. Which one would tell me if it's loading my Custom Code? When I go to Schedule a task my scheduled tasks appear in the Class dropdown list. So that makes me think it's registering the custom code.

Comment: You would find "CustomTask1" and "CustomTask1" as custom modules in that list of items.